# When can I return to Singapore?

Tags: visas, singapore, visas-on-arrival

I have been visiting Singapore for three months using the white card. Every two or three weeks I have come back to Malaysia and returned to Singapore using the white card. However, recently the officer told me that I have only two days left on my quota for Singapore.

When can I return to Singapore? How can I know when I can return? Is the any official website I can check?

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge (I lived in Singapore for ~8 years and moderated [an expat forum](http://forum.singaporeexpats.com/) there), **Singapore does not publish any official guidelines for repeat visits**.  However, it's a very small country with limited opportunities for tourism, and as you've discovered, around the three-month mark Immigration's bells start ringing.  Once you're flagged, you're usually only given one warning and are likely to be denied entry next time.

You did not say *why* you're visiting Singapore so often, but the solution is simple at least in theory: **get an actual visa**.  Work visa if you're working, [social visit pass](http://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=180) if you're visiting friends or family, etc.